# Append text after last occurance of matched line

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a tool that generates some source code.  Unfortunately, the tool skips a using clause from the source.

Using a utility like sed, how do I insert into a source file a line such as

```
using namespace xyz;
```

To appear only once and after the last line to contain #include ?

e.g.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// some functions
void blabla();
```

Would become:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace xyz;  

// some functions
void blabla();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/#include/) nr=NR; next} {print; if(nr==FNR) print "\nusing namespace xyz;"}' file file
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace xyz;


// some functions
void blabla();
```

The above is using 2 passes - the first to find the line number where the last occurrence of `#include` appears in the file and storing it's line number in a variable named `nr` and then the 2nd to print "using ..." when that line number is hit on that 2nd pass. You can do it without specifying the file name twice by changing `awk 'script' file file` to `awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[1]; ARGC++} script' file` if you prefer to duplicate the file name in the arguments list array.

Alternatively if the file's not huge you can read it all into memory and then do a substitution treating the whole file as a single string, e.g. with GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -vRS='^$' -voORS= '{print gensub(/(.*#include[^\n]+\n)/,"\\1\nusing namespace xyz;\n",1)}' file
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace xyz;


// some functions
void blabla();
```

With other awks you'd build up the string line by line into a variable then process that in the END section using match() and substr():

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{ if (match(rec,/.*#include[^\n]+\n/)) rec = substr(rec,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) "\nusing namespace xyz;\n" substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH); print rec}' file
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace xyz;


// some functions
void blabla();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  No output is produced.  I'm using gawk 4.0.1

Comment: ahh, I have to put the file twice?  why is that?

Comment: I added an explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;/.*#include[^\n]*\n/s//&\ninsert a line here\n/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and using greed find the last line with the required string and then insert the required string.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into simple steps: find the lines with `#include`, find the last line number of these, append your extra line(s) at that line.

```
lno=$( sed <file -n '/^#include/=' | sed -n '$p' )
sed -i file -e "$lno"'a\
\
using namespace xyz;
'
```

This sets the bash variable `lno` to the last line number (printed by sed `=`).
The last `sed` appends a blank line and your line after that line, editing the file inplace.